# How to get the data in a given time period

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models

I try to do the following query to give me the tournaments in this period:

```
sart_date = 2014-05-01 00:00:00
end_date = 2014-05-31 23:59:59
```

Here is the code I use for this purpose:

```
start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(request.GET['start_date'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(request.GET['end_date'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    upcoming = Tournament.objects.filter(Q(started__gte=start_date), Q(ended__lte=end_date),
                                         Q(championship_id=championship_id))
    print upcoming.query
```

When you print an application I get the following condition:

```
.....WHERE (`tournaments_tournament`.`started` >= 2014-04-30 21:00:00  AND `tournaments_tournament`.`ended` <= 2014-05-31 20:59:59  AND `tournaments_tournament`.`championship_id` = 11 )....
```

Here is how the fields appear in the model:

```
started = models.DateTimeField (_('start date and time'))
ended = models.DateTimeField (_('end date and time'), null = True, blank=True)
```

Does anyone have any idea why so obtained and there is a way to fix this?

Comment: what sql statement were you trying to get? this seems like you got the exact query you were asking for.

Comment: I want to receive the following: ```.....WHERE (`tournaments_tournament`.`started` >= 2014-05-01 00:00:00  AND `tournaments_tournament`.`ended` <= 2014-05-31 23:59:59  AND `tournaments_tournament`.`championship_id` = 11 )....```

Comment: isn't that what you said you were getting above? I'm confused, by your question, I think it may be the way it is phrased.

Comment: See the date and time, there is a difference.

Comment: This looks like a time zone problem. Do you happen to have `USE_TZ` enabled in your django settings? Then all DateTimeFields are UTC and time zone aware. Please refer to this documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/timezones/

Comment: Thanks a lot right there was the problem. I had to convert the local time which is set. thank you!